# Using line profiler with multiprocessing

Tags: python, profiling, python-multiprocessing, line-profiler

How can you profile a python module that use multiprocessing (multiprocessing.Pool.map) so each spawned process will be also profiled line by line.

Currently I use line_profiler for profiling but it doesn't support multiprocessing.
Is there a way to do it manually? Or maybe use some other tool?

Answer (score 4):

The normal way of using [line_profiler](https://github.com/pyutils/line_profiler) of adding `@profile` to the function being profiled and running `kernprof -v -l script.py` leads to the following error for multiprocessing:

```
Can't pickle <class '__main__.Worker'>: attribute lookup Worker on __main__ failed.
```

To fix this, we have to setup the `line_profiler` ourselves in the sub-process we want to profile, rather than doing it globally via `kernelprof`:

```py
import multiprocessing as mp
import line_profiler

class Worker(mp.Process):

    def run(self):
        prof = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
        # Wrap all functions that you want to be profiled in this process
        # These can be global functions or any class methods
        # Make sure to replace instance methods on a class level, not the bound methods self.run2
        Worker.run2 = prof(Worker.run2)
        ...
        # run the main
        self.run2()
        # store stats in separate file for each process
        prof.dump_stats('worker.lprof')

    def run2(self):
        # real run method renamed
        ...
```

Now running the script this generates a profile file that we can then visualize with:

```
python -m line_profiler worker.lprof
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use [memory_profiler](https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/) like this

```py
from memory_profiler import profile
import multiprocessing as mp
import time, psutil, gc, os


@profile(precision=4)
def array_ops(num):
    gc.collect()
    size1 = 10 ** num
    size2 = 20 ** (num+1)
    x = [1] * size1
    y = [2] * size2
    y *= 2
    del y
    gc.collect()
    z = x * 2
    gc.collect()
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    num_workers = 3
    pool = mp.Pool(num_workers)
    pool.map(array_ops, [4,5,6])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

This is a sample output

```sh
Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6  34.4258 MiB  34.4258 MiB   @profile(precision=4)
     7                             def array_ops(num):
     8  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
     9  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       size1 = 10 ** num
    10  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       size2 = 20 ** (num+1)
    11  34.5586 MiB   0.1328 MiB       x = [1] * size1
    12  58.7852 MiB  24.2266 MiB       y = [2] * size2
    13  83.2539 MiB  24.4688 MiB       y *= 2
    14  34.6055 MiB   0.0000 MiB       del y
    15  34.6055 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
    16  34.6055 MiB   0.0000 MiB       z = x * 2
    17  34.6055 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
    18  34.6055 MiB   0.0000 MiB       return x


Filename: array_ops.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6  34.4258 MiB  34.4258 MiB   @profile(precision=4)
     7                             def array_ops(num):
     8  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
     9  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       size1 = 10 ** num
    10  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       size2 = 20 ** (num+1)
    11  35.0820 MiB   0.6562 MiB       x = [1] * size1
    12 523.3711 MiB 488.2891 MiB       y = [2] * size2
    13 1011.6172 MiB 488.2461 MiB       y *= 2
    14  35.2969 MiB   0.0000 MiB       del y
    15  35.2969 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
    16  36.5703 MiB   1.2734 MiB       z = x * 2
    17  36.5703 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
    18  36.8242 MiB   0.2539 MiB       return x


Filename: array_ops.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment   Line Contents
================================================
     6  34.4258 MiB  34.4258 MiB   @profile(precision=4)
     7                             def array_ops(num):
     8  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
     9  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       size1 = 10 ** num
    10  34.4258 MiB   0.0000 MiB       size2 = 20 ** (num+1)
    11  42.0391 MiB   7.6133 MiB       x = [1] * size1
    12 9807.7109 MiB 9765.6719 MiB       y = [2] * size2
    13 19573.2109 MiB 9765.5000 MiB       y *= 2
    14  42.1641 MiB   0.0000 MiB       del y
    15  42.1641 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
    16  57.3594 MiB  15.1953 MiB       z = x * 2
    17  57.3594 MiB   0.0000 MiB       gc.collect()
    18  57.3594 MiB   0.0000 MiB       return x
```