# Why line_profiler enable and disable output only 'Timer unit'?

Tags: python, line-profiler

## enviroment

- python 3.9
- line-profiler 3.1.0

I installed line-profiler by pip.

`sudo pip3 install line-profiler`

## detail

`add_function` and `runcall` works. that's ok.

```py
import line_profiler

def hoge():
    n = 0
    for i in range(100):
        n += i
    print(n)

pr = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
pr.add_function(hoge)
pr.runcall(hoge)
pr.print_stats()
```

```
% python3.9 profile1.py
4950
Timer unit: 1e-06 s

Total time: 6.1e-05 s
File: /home/miwa/work/lang/python/profile1.py
Function: hoge at line 4

Line #      Hits         Time  Per Hit   % Time  Line Contents
==============================================================
     4                                           def hoge():
     5         1          1.0      1.0      1.6      n = 0
     6       101         23.0      0.2     37.7      for i in range(100):
     7       100         25.0      0.2     41.0          n += i
     8         1         12.0     12.0     19.7      print(n)
```

but `enable` and `disable` does not work.

Output only 'Timer unit' .

Is it used incorrectly?

```py
import line_profiler

def hoge():
    n = 0
    for i in range(100):
        n += i
    print(n)

pr = line_profiler.LineProfiler()
pr.enable()
hoge()
pr.disable()
pr.print_stats()
```

```
% python3.9 profile0.py
4950
Timer unit: 1e-06 s
```

Comment: I'm running into the same issue where line_profiler is only outputting the timer unit after executing the profiler. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems `line-profiler` cannot be used in the same way as cProfile (enable - run - disable syntax). Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67969672/4976878) for two alternative ways.